# Php error file handling

Tags: php

When PHP code

```
error_log("1. Error: " . $_FILES['uploaded_file1']['error']);
```

prints

```
"... stderr: PHP message: 1.Error: "
```

what does it mean? I expect that `$_FILES['uploaded_file1']['error']` will return  Error code from 0-8 and not Nothing.

Comment: Does `var_dump($_FILES['uploaded_file1'])` show any content? It's possible that file field doesn't exist in the submitted data (either because there is no field with that name on the form or because it wasn't submitted with the right `enctype`, or for some other reason). Certainly if I tried to access `$_FILES['lalalalalafoobar']['error']` that wouldn't exist either.

Comment: Yes, now I see that there is nothing. I just expect, if there is nothing I will receive error code `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP only populates `$_FILES` with keys that actually exist on the form. Imagine if it didn't. It would have to create `$_FILES['a']`, `$_FILES['aa']`, `$_FILES['aaaaaaaaaaaa']` — in fact, it would have to fill in every possible field name in the universe (which is infinitely many) on the off chance you might try to look for an error code on one of them.

You should first check to see if `isset($_FILES['uploaded_file1'])` which tells you if PHP even attempted to look for a file with that name. If it's missing, that's not the same thing as `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`.